# Accessing Azure app configuration in a WCF service

Tags: authentication, wcf, azure-app-configuration

We have an on-prem WCF service. Recently we added Azure app config to store some config values. We use certificate based authentication(using service principal) to access Azure App config. The issue is, when we try to connect to the Azure app config from WCF service, we get authentication failed error. We can successfully connect to and access the config values from Azure, using a console app in the same server using the same certificate.
The service account of WCF has all the access to manage the certificate. Why can't we access Azure app config in WCF service? Are we missing any settings?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possibly a configuration issue in web.config`<security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
          </security>`
You can check [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/setting-up-client-certificate-authentication-for-wcf-service/ba-p/2276552).

Comment: Hi @LanHuang, Thanks for the info. But my issue was not related to it. It turned out to be a missing DLL issue. I am using Global.asax > application_start event to load the Azure app config values, for some reason I was getting authentication failed error for missing DLL. I moved the loading method out of Global.asax and it started showing the actual missing DLL errors. Once I added all the DLLs in the bin, I was able to connect to the Azure app config and load all the values. Thanks for the link you shared.

Comment: This issue is now resolved. Closing the thread.